# R: NaNs produced in Log-Likelihood optimisation

Tags: r, optimization

I am working on identifying svar models and do have some questions about the following looklikehood function

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjjHs.jpg

We want to estimate the values of B_22, which is a 2x2 matrix, and Omega (in my code I call this matrix „L“), which has the unknown parameters on the diagonal and zero else. Thus:

```
B <- matrix(c(theta[1:4]),nrow=2,ncol=2)
```

(edit:Omega:)

```
L <- matrix(c(theta[5],0,0,theta[6]),nrow=2,ncol=2)
```

Sigma1 and Sigma2 are known and estimate with a 2xn vector "u", which has been choosen arbitrarily.

1. When I compute the code, I get dozens of errors because the log(det(.)) produces negative values. This should not be possible since B* t(B) and B* L* t(B) are covariance matrices and thus their determinant must be positive. I have read several posts about using estimation method L-BFGS-B and restricting the parameters, but (i) applying the lowerbound gives me an error in the source code and (ii) I am not sure whether restricting the parameters in such a way will distort the optimisation results. How can I solve this problem? Is L-BFGS-B-method with restricting parameters the right way to go?
2. My second question is regarding starting values oft he optim() function. I do have realised that changing the starting values leads to different optimisation outcome. How do I interpret this result? Does that mean that the model I am trying to estimate is not sufficiently identified?

I hope the information I have given is enough to answer my questions and my format is readable. Any help or hints (also on my coding, since I am relatively new to programming/R-coding) is appreciated.

```
 LL<-function(theta,u){
  sig1<-1/63*u[,1:63]%*%t(u[,1:63]) #breaking points 63,28 has been choosen arbirarily
  sig2<-1/28*u[,64:92]%*%t(u[,64:92])
  B<-matrix(c(theta[1:4]),nrow=2,ncol=2)
  L<-matrix(c(theta[5],0,0,theta[6]),nrow=2,ncol=2)
logl<- -(63/2)*(log(det(B%*%t(B)))       +  sum(diag(sig1%*%solve(B%*%t(B))))) -   (28/2)*(log(det(B%*%L%*%t(B)))   +  sum(diag(sig2%*%solve(B%*%L%*%t(B)))))
return(-logl)
}

x1<-optim(c(17,5,3,4,27,13),LL,method="BFGS",u=u)


u[1,]   -2.0739942  -2.152562   6.3569442   8.813618    -4.4750621  -2.20355587 -2.32608476 -5.32235864 -1.1783355  2.3010929   -2.3281323  4.8122883   -0.6523752  2.1975880   4.4731109   -3.880578   2.82303865  -0.29450020 -2.2489995  -7.2447985  4.996482982 1.04475829  0.2690333   -5.4314632  4.5957677   -0.9616699  0.5806076   1.6844795   -5.1626010  -1.2564188  -3.0584362  2.34260683  -1.695052   3.51939426  4.43626989  3.3296631   3.5169510   -2.92703345 -1.4131281  7.66182944  -1.40676753 -3.70130317 -0.9010226  -3.91265962 -0.85604657 0.6541337   -3.3668541  -9.7513509  -2.2203572  0.348708268 -0.51795228 -2.644891   -0.2826551  -3.5819070  -2.2470037  -3.829720   0.7522229   1.57592864  -1.15328558 2.9035609   6.7805296   3.2419771   5.607151    0.4836202   2.6242557   3.4674478   0.3317039   3.661060    -2.7323857  -3.85183300 -13.91937338    -29.9294984 -0.4273221  1.96726064  4.0437405   3.505792    12.0125181  3.7582406   3.7173530   11.0320698  0.2876495   1.7703799   -0.75943651 1.38642025  0.1694661   -0.09183614 -3.4427353  -3.42262435 4.56156149  1.27963086  2.3382191   4.471848294 -1.25201443
u[2,]   -0.4976848  -0.337874   -0.4690339  1.376631    -0.2000215  -0.07479611 -0.09590784 0.01132767  0.0859742   0.2965264   0.1478579   -0.1033833  -0.1089317  -0.3412644  -0.4387209  -0.295550   -0.04845632 0.01153943  0.1252204   0.2691985   0.006748248 0.03430976  0.1910270   0.4734956   0.1047363   0.2233812   0.1416566   -0.1008976  -0.3944692  -0.3639312  -0.1398038  -0.01805854 -0.144216   -0.03937892 -0.09407875 -0.2500851  -0.5786795  -0.05531415 -0.1411416  -0.03722923 -0.01203752 0.07773881  0.2560005   0.06210876  0.09857757  0.1958526   0.3224293   0.4340536   0.1937018   0.001760465 0.04619835  -0.089682   0.2107282   0.2445777   0.2605063   1.170965    0.1568308   -0.03179252 -0.06910847 0.1334419   -0.2214261  -0.2858338  -0.284578   -0.4268307  -0.2218157  -0.1590297  -0.1605659  -0.341321   -0.0825591  -0.09752851 0.08405546  0.3481321   0.3238180   -0.03529309 -0.1181096  -0.080112   -0.2421429  -0.1098334  -0.1149457  -0.0409451  -0.1428287  -0.0220812  -0.06036089 0.04192624  0.0760739   0.07842770  0.1800529   0.07780021  0.04023444  0.04337697  0.1267495   -0.002556303    0.0364775
```

Comment: We can't reproduce the problem without your `u matrix`. For you second question , It can be due to the fact that your functionyou try to optimize have many local minimals. Changing the starting point , can change the gradient direction and the final result.. For your first question , my advise is you should try to plot your function before minimizing it ( even in smaller dimensions), the more information you have the easier you can solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advise so far, meanwhile I added the u-matrix to my original post, if anyone wants to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optim converges with your initial parameters, so I'm not sure there is a problem.  But, you can also try using the alternative optimization routines and run a simple test to see what parameters are giving warnings

```
## Test results with other methods
x1 <- optim(c(17,5,3,4,27,13),LL,method="BFGS",u=u)
ps <- x1$par
x2 <- optim(ps, LL, method="Nelder-Mead", u=u)
x3 <- optim(ps, LL, method="SANN", u=u, control=list(maxit=1e5))

## Try some theta values (arbitrary)
tst <- expand.grid(-1:1, -1:1, -1:1, -1:1, -1:1, -1:1)
res <- apply(tst, 1, function(r) {
    tryCatch ({ 
        LL(r, u) 
    }, error=function(e) print ( r ))
})
```

There are warnings with negative/zero values of some thetas (would need to look closer to see which ones).  You could use "L-BFGS-B" to constrain your theta values to always be positive (except for theta[1] which is negative in the fitted parameters).

```
x4 <- optim(ps, LL, u=u, method="L-BFGS-B", lower=c(-Inf, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            upper=rep(Inf, 6))  # no warnings
```

Percent differences between estimates and expected values for theta

```
sig1<-1/63*u[,1:63]%*%t(u[,1:63]) #breaking points 63,28 has been choosen arbirarily
sig2<-1/28*u[,64:92]%*%t(u[,64:92])
B <- matrix(x1$par[1:4], 2, 2)
sig2hat <- B%*%matrix(c(x1$par[5],0,0,x1$par[6]), 2, 2)%*%t(B)
data.frame(
    estimates=c(
        as.vector(B%*%B),
        diag(sig2hat)),
    expected=c(as.vector(sig1), diag(sig2)),
    percent=c(
        as.vector((B%*%B - sig1) / sig1 * 100),
        as.vector((sig2hat-sig2)/sig2*100)[c(2, 4)])
)
#     estimates    expected       percent
# 1 13.70655766 13.70602733  3.869312e-03
# 2 -0.15511643 -0.16220783 -4.371801e+00
# 3 -0.07984098 -0.16220783 -5.077859e+01
# 4  0.10278075  0.10379904 -9.810168e-01
# 5 55.29850597 55.29852730 -3.833837e-04
# 6  0.03042440  0.03042414  8.412705e-04
```

Comment: Thanks, now I know in which direction to focus, this helps alot!

Comment: To throw in one general question about the MLE at hand: The idea is to get consistent estimators of B and L, s.t. B%*%B = sig1 and B%*%L%*%t(B) (right?). This imply that B%*%t(B)  and B%*%L%*%t(B) should be somewhat similiar to sig1 and sig2, respectively. With the current output this is not even close to be the case. Does this imply that there is some statistical error prior to the optimisation process, e.g. sig1 and sig2 are wrongly choosen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The estimates don't look that far off. `B <- matrix(x1$par[1:4], 2, 2); as.vector((B%*%B - sig1) / sig1 * 100); sig2hat <- B%*%matrix(c(x1$par[5],0,0,x1$par[6]), 2, 2)%*%t(B); as.vector((sig2-sig2hat)/sig2*100)`.  The worst is theta[3] by the looks of it.

Comment: How do I interpret these values in your code? These are the t-values, correct?

Comment: Those are percent differences, so  `(B%*%B)[3]` is (-)50% off the value of `sig1[3]`.

Comment: With optimization method of the above did you use for this? When I ur command I get values of `41473.6133 -1075125.2442    -1793.7651      138.9493`, for the sig1 estimate and something simliar for sig2...

Comment: I hate to ask this last question, but could you also provide your complete code of optimization. I get really strange values for this. Besides that, you have been a big help, thanks alot!

Comment: sorry, I don't know what to tell you, that is the whole code.  If the expected `sig1` and `sig2` are different, maybe the `u` matrix is changed.

Comment: You are right, I changed u in the proccess of "fixing" code (it has been a long day...). Thanks alot for your help, I was stuck at this for the entire weekend and now can work on. Cheers!